# ORDER BY Year DESC Not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have some info im displaying on my page. I got it to display the content of my table perfectly. However when i try to sort it everything breaks. Any advice will be appreciated

```
$sql = "

SELECT * 

 FROM 

 agreements ORDER BY Year DESC 

 WHERE

  1 = 1

  ".($_POST['agreeno'] != '' ? "AND Resolution = '".$_POST['agreeno']."'" : Null)."

  ".($_POST['keyword'] != '' ? "AND Resolution_Name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%'" : Null)."

  ".($_POST['Year'] != '' ? "AND Year LIKE '%".$_POST['Year']."%'" : Null). "

"

;
```

Here is my complete code.

```
// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 



echo "<table class='table table-striped publications' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td style='text-align: left;' align='center'><strong>Resolution Name</strong></td>

<td ><strong>Resolution</strong></td>

<td><strong>Year</strong></td>

<td><strong>Department</strong></td>

<td><strong>Document</strong></td>

</tr>"; 













$sql = "

 SELECT * 

 FROM 

 agreements ORDER BY Year DESC 

 WHERE

  1 = 1

  ".($_POST['agreeno'] != '' ? "AND Resolution = '".$_POST['agreeno']."'" : Null)."

  ".($_POST['keyword'] != '' ? "AND Resolution_Name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%'" : Null)."

  ".($_POST['Year'] != '' ? "AND Year LIKE '%".$_POST['Year']."%'" : Null). "

"

;








$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {



    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {





 echo "<tr><td style='text-align: left' align='center'>" . $row["Resolution_Name"]. "</td><td style='text-align: left;' align='center'> " . $row["Resolution"]. " </td><td style='text-align: left;' align='center'> " . $row["Year"]. " </td><td style='text-align: left;' align='center'> " . $row["Department"]. "</td><td style='text-align: left;' align='center'> <a href='". $row["Document"]. "' target='_empty'>View Document [PDF]</a> </td></tr>";

    }

} else {

    echo "0 results";

}

$conn->close();



echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: `echo $sql` and show us the final sql query

Comment: The year is a drop down in the front end with pre-defined values when the user posts a document version.

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause should come after `WHERE`

Comment: Change the order of `order by` clause.  `order by` is coming after `where` clause.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: This is the result of the query without the order desc . [link]http://imgur.com/joiyydo

Comment: If i add the order the page is blank

Comment: @Andrew did you move the order by to the end of the statement as advised?

Comment: Yes i have but getting a Parse error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $_POST' (T_VARIABLE), expecting' and this is on that line ".($_POST['keyword'] != '' ? "AND Resolution_Name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%'" : Null)."

Comment: for your error i have added code in answer use it... !empty() or isset() will remove your above error  @Andrew

Comment: Use `prepared statements` in query to avoid SQL Injection when you are adding `user input( using any HTTP methods like GET, POST`) to the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ORDER BY` comes after `WHERE` condition.

Also use `empty()` or `isset()` with post values to prevent from undefine index error.

```
$sql = "

SELECT * 

 FROM 

 agreements 

 WHERE

  1 = 1

  ".((!empty($_POST['agreeno'])) ? "AND Resolution = '".$_POST['agreeno']."'" : Null)."

  ".((!empty$_POST['keyword'])) != '' ? "AND Resolution_Name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%'" : Null)."

  ".((!empty($_POST['Year'])) != '' ? "AND Year LIKE '%".$_POST['Year']."%'" : Null). "

ORDER BY Year DESC 
"
;
```

Comment: ohhhh yes in comment.. :)

Comment: Use this answer will solve your both problem `ORDER BY` and  `syntax error`... @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "

SELECT * 

 FROM 

 agreements 

 WHERE

  1 = 1

  ".($_POST['agreeno'] != '' ? "AND Resolution = '".$_POST['agreeno']."'" : "")."

  ".($_POST['keyword'] != '' ? "AND Resolution_Name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%'" : "")."

  ".($_POST['Year'] != '' ? "AND Year LIKE '%".$_POST['Year']."%'" : ""). "

 ORDER BY Year DESC 
"

;
```

Comment: Good Answer will include some explanation